# Dynamically add or remove elements according to the value of checked radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some radio buttons with numeric values, that stand for the number of elements that should be rendered when I select one or another button. Here are they:

```
<input type="radio" id="one" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="1" />
<input type="radio" id="two" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="2" />
<input type="radio" id="three" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="3" />
<input type="radio" id="four" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="4" />
```

And I've got, for example, a `<div></div>`, which should be rendered the number of times that corresponds to checked input value. For example, if I check `input#one`, I should get rendered a `<div></div>`. If I check `input#two`, there must be `<div></div> <div></div>`, and so on. Accordingly, if I checked, for example `input#three` and got rendered three `<div></div>`s,  and then check an input with lesser value (i.e. 1 or 2), it should display exactly this number of elemets, and not appending the new to existing ones. I tried to make it like this

```
$('.render-input').change(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i++)
        $(this).append('<div></div>');
});
```

But then the only way to decrement the number of elements rendered if an input with lesser value was checked is to remove all the elements and render them again, and this doesn't seem as a right and proper way to do that. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue here is that you're trying to append a `div` to an `input`, which is not possible. It would make more sense to specify a containing element and append them there. Also note that you should parse the value of the selected radio as an integer. Try this:

```js
$('.render-input').change(function() {
  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(this.value, 10); i++) {
    html += '<div></div>';
  }
  $('#container').html(html);
});
```

```css
#container div { 
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #c00;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="one" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="1" />
<input type="radio" id="two" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="2" />
<input type="radio" id="three" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="3" />
<input type="radio" id="four" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="4" />

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
<input type="radio" id="one" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="1" />
<input type="radio" id="two" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="2" />
<input type="radio" id="three" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="3" />
<input type="radio" id="four" class="render-input" name="renderVal" value="4" />
 <span id="output"></span>

$('.render-input').change(function () {
var val="";
for (var i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i++)
    val+='<div>Hi</div>';
$("#output").html(val);  

});
```

Check its output here https://jsfiddle.net/11Lrwtue/